# Why are pipes rusting and bursting

Tags: simcity-4

In Sim City 4, I have a small city with population 1000. I have one water tower and pipes to give the entire area coverage. I'm using about 1/6 of the water tower's capacity. I've funded the water utility over 100%.

However, I'm getting burst and newly rusted pipes every month. I've repiped, pushed utility finding to the max and this doesn't slow down the bursting.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are the pipes going over area with heavy water pollution?

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual for pipes to be an issue if Water Dept  funding is at the recommended level. Sometimes if the funding for that deptartment has been lowered in the past, problems can persist after normal funding has returned.

Try removing all of the problem pipes and placing down new ones after the funding is at the white line.